# How to tell the difference between Edit Mode and Personalized Edit Mode

Tags: web-part, personalization, edit-form

I have a page where I need to pick a list to store information. This is either a global list for all users, or a personal list for the specific user.

The current practice is to detect edit vs browse with `WebPartManager.DisplayMode.Name` but this doesn't distinguish between the two types of edit modes.

How do I tell one from the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebPartManager.DisplayMode` gives you the mode of the page: Browse, Edit, ...

`WebPartManager.Personalization.Scope` gives you the scope of the page: Shared or User